# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array using O(1) Auxiliary Space (LeetCode)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, duplicates, c++14

This is my function

```
class Solution {

public:

    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {

        auto i = nums.begin();
        int prev = *i;
        i++;

        for(;i!=nums.end();i++){

            if(*i == prev){
                nums.erase(i);
            }
            prev = *i;
        }

        return (int)nums.size();
    }
};
```

It is calling the vector by reference so we have to return length of the modified vector which is without duplicates.

What is wrong with it and how to improve the answer?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: @user4581301 The title says "Remove Duplicates from **Sorted** Array"

Comment: Done deal. Missed the word.

Comment: BTW, there is no requirement that a C++ program can only execute functions via classes.  IMHO, this should be a free standing function.  The `main` is an example of a free standing function.

Comment: Agree with @ThomasMatthews ,but in this case you're stuck. Online Judges require you to meet their specified requirements exactly.

Comment: @OP -- if the array is sorted, there is a better solution than the one you've attempted.  First, `std::unique` already does this work for you, and if you see how it is [implemented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), you should see that it simply copies the unique element into the non-unique element position while traversing the array.  Then the only thing left to do is one single `erase`, where you are erasing from the last unique position + 1 until the end of the array (which is what `vector.erase` would have done).

Comment: @OP -- Since your solution repeatedly calls `erase`, and you're using online judge competition sites to test your code, remember that these sites have questions that are designed to give time-out errors if the input is very large.  For example, if the string contained thousands of characters and many duplicates, your solution may give a time out error due to the calls to `erase` for every duplicate found.  Thus a more safer solution would be to copy the values similar to `std::unique`, and then do one single erasure at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) will invalidate iterators and return new iterator, so you should catch the returned iterator.

Try this:

```
class Solution {

public:

    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {

        auto i = nums.begin();
        int prev = *i;
        i++;

        for(;i!=nums.end();){

            if(*i == prev){
                i = nums.erase(i);
            } else {
                prev = *i;
                i++;
            }
        }

        return (int)nums.size();
    }
};
```

or simpler one:

```
#include <algorithm>

class Solution {

public:

    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {

        auto i = std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        nums.erase(i, nums.end());

        return (int)nums.size();
    }
};
```

Comment: what does i = nums.erase(i) mean??

Comment: i mean what does it return to i?

Comment: It will return an iterator pointed at the next element (or end of vector) of the erased element.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `erase`, this'd also pass through:

```
// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;

#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// Start
static const struct Solution {
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast32_t;
    static const int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums) {
        SizeType len = std::size(nums);
        SizeType count = 0;

        for (auto i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
            if (nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) {
                ++count;

            } else {
                nums[i - count] = nums[i];
            }
        }

        return len - count;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.